# Does anyone know the easiest way of replacing tags and everything in between them in multiple html files?

Tags: php, html, shell, applescript, automator

I have a lot of html files with custom style sheets within. I would like to create one universal style sheet that they all can use. 
So what i need to do is replace

> < style type="text/css">
>
> .Title {....
>   .body {..
>
> < /style>

including the tags with this in multiple html files.

> < link media="screen" href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Im sure someone has ran into this problem and im wondering what would be the easiest way to accomplish this task? is there some kind of applescript or php script i can run to do this or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: This post may help as well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227097/parsing-html-source-code-using-applescript/10230916#10230916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd usually just use TextMate's Search in Project or some Ruby or shell script. I have a script like this saved as `ggsub.rb` and just modify it when I need to replace something in multiple files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -Ku

# paths = `find ~/Sites -name '*.html'`.chomp.split("\n")
paths = Dir["*.html"]

paths.each do |path|
  html = File.read(path)
  html.sub!(/<style.*?>.*?<\/style>/m,
  "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">")
  puts html
  # File.open(path, "w") { |f| f.puts(html) }
end
```

Comment: This worked. Just uncomented the File.open and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

See the accepted answer to this question, posted earlier today.

[How to remove entire div with preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658770/how-to-remove-entire-div-with-preg-replace/10658809#10658809)

It's very close to what you're trying to do. In short, use the DOMDocument class - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Thanks for the reference. used the ruby script instead and it worked like a charm. Did not activate apache on my mac yet.